# Unexpected results from SGEMM

Tags: fortran, gfortran, blas

I'm trying to replace the following instance of matmul in the code calculating A*B':

```
print *, mat%A
print *, mat%B
print *, mat%dimsA
print *, mat%dimsB
C = matmul(mat%A,transpose(mat%B))
print *, C
```

with SGEMM:

```
print *, mat%A
print *, mat%B
print *, mat%dimsA
print *, mat%dimsB
call SGEMM('N', 'T', mat%dimsA(1), mat%dimsB(1), mat%dimsA(2), 1, mat%A, &
    mat%dimsA(1), mat%B, mat%dimsB(1), 0, C, mat%dimsA(1))
print *, C
```

Where mat is an type that contains the following relevant data:

```
integer :: dimsA(2), dimsB(2)
real, pointer :: A(:,:),B(:,:)
```

Running the code on a small test where A is:

```
1 1 1 
2 2 2
```

and B is:

```
1 1 1
```

I get the following outputs for matmul:

```
1.00000000       2.00000000       1.00000000       2.00000000       1.00000000       2.00000000    
1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000    
2           3
1           3
3.00000000       6.00000000
```

and SGEMM:

```
1.00000000       2.00000000       1.00000000       2.00000000       1.00000000       2.00000000    
1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000    
2           3
1           3
4.20389539E-45   8.40779079E-45
```

Am I wrong in assuming these two blocks of code should have the same result?

Comment: If you're doing this for performance reasons,  you could also use -fexternal-blas option which makes GFortran matmul use Blas under the covers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are passing integers for alpha and beta to the lapack subroutine. The compiler does not have the interface of `SGEMM` available and cannot warn you of the resulting type confusion...

Just use the notation for (default precision) reals - `1.` instead of `1`, and `0.` instead of `0`:

```
call SGEMM('N', 'T', mat%dimsA(1), mat%dimsB(1), mat%dimsA(2), 1., mat%A, &
    mat%dimsA(1), mat%B, mat%dimsB(1), 0., C, mat%dimsA(1))
```